# Will the facebook sdk 3.0 support iOS 4?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I have my app developed for iOS 4.3 to 6 and it uses facebook sdk 3.1. But now I require to prepare a build using xcode 4.2 to make the app runs on a device that has iOS 4.0 . Will the facebook sdk 3.0 support iOS version 4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It supports versions 4.3 and up. See https://developers.facebook.com/ios/features/whats-new-ios-sdk-3.1/, the section in Facebook Login.

Comment: I have already read the link you posted. Its about facebook sdk 3.1.

Comment: ...and facebook SDK v3.5 removed support for iOS4. http://developers.facebook.com/ios/change-log-3.x/ "Removes support for iOS 4.* Facebook 6.0 dropped support for iOS 4.x."